# Polymorphism calling a function from the base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

So I have these classes:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
   Base() {cout << "made a base" << endl;}
   virtual void getType() const { cout << "Im a base" << endl;
   virtual ~Base() {}
   //other members...
}

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived() {cout << "made a derived" << endl;
    virtual void getType() const { cout << "Im a derived" << endl; }
    virtual ~Derived() {}
    //other memebrs...
}


int main() {

    Base* test = new Derived();
    test->getType();

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```sh
made a base
made a derived
Im a derived
```

Now I know that the output is `Im a derived` because of polymorphism, however I would like to know how this works internally with Vftables, how can It call the correct function, the vtable inside `test` points to the Base class `getType()` function because of the type of `test` so how can it know that it is `Derived::getType()` and not `Base::getType()`.in other words what does my program do at runtime when it see's this declaration `test->getType()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `Base* test = new Derived()`:

The V-Table pointer of object `test` is set to point to the V-Table of class `Derived`.

Note that when the object is created - via `new Derived()` - you are explicitly calling a function (the constructor) of class `Derived` and not of class `Base`.

And when this function is called, it sets the v-table pointer of the new object to point to the V-Table of class `Derived` and not of class `Base`.

AFAIK, the actual V-Tables (of both classes), are generated by the linker past compilation.

**Supplemental:**

The program doesn't need to "know" that a function is `virtual`.

In case of a non-virtual function call, the compiler adds a JUMP instruction to a constant address (i.e., the address of the non-virtual function, which is resolvable during compilation).

In case of a virtual function call, the compiler adds a JUMP instruction to an address stored in (pointed by) a variable, whose value is resolved only during runtime.

Comment: @Alex: It's not a function, it is an array of pointers (pointers to functions). The V-Table of class `Derived` contains the addresses (i.e., function pointers) of all virtual functions in this class.

Comment: And the V-Table pointer of object `test` is set to point to the V-Table of that class.

Comment: @Alex: Note that when the object is created - via `new Derived()` - you are explicitly calling a function (the constructor) of class `Derived` and not of class `Base`. And when the constructor of `Derived` is called, it sets the v-table pointer of the new object to point to the V-Table of class `Derived` (which the linker generates past compilation).

Comment: @Alex: NP, but which part? I'm pretty sure I've explained that in the answer, no?

Comment: your last comment before this one with the helpful vote :D

Comment: @Alex: `class Derived: public Base` indicates that, and the addresses of all functions declared `virtual` are added to the V-Table.

Comment: @Alex: I answered polymorphism.

Comment: Oh, so I guess it just checks if both classes have a vtable then at runtime?

Comment: @Alex: The program doesn't need to "know" that. In case of a non-virtual function call, the compiler adds a JUMP instruction to a constant address (i.e., the address of the function, which is resolvable during compilation). In case of a virtual function call, the compiler adds a JUMP instruction to a non-constant address (i.e., an address stored in a variable, whose value is resolved during runtime).